# Ruby on Rails: Linking issue between pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I'm fairly new to Ruby and Rails and this has been an issue I can't resolve on my own:

I'm working on an existing website, running on an older version of Rails and Ruby 1.9.3.

I'm trying to change the details for a certain user, but sometimes in the linking I don't get http://127.0.0.1:3000/users/firstname.lastname but http://127.0.0.1:3000/users?id=firstname.lastname.

This is the code for the links I have:

```
<li><%= link_to "Remove this user", user_path(@person[:uid]), :confirm => 'Are you sure you want to delete ' + @person[:uid] + '?',:method => :delete ,:title => "Delete user from LDAP" %></li>
<li><%= link_to "Edit this user", edit_userdetails_path(id:@username[:UserID]) %></li>
<li><%= link_to "Add to group", group_path %></li>
<li><%= link_to "Change password", change_pwd_path(@person[:uid]) %></li>
```

The first and 3rd link work like they should, the 2nd and 4th link have the behavior as described with the ?id= in the url.

This is what's in my routes file:

```
resources :posts
resources :timesheets
resources :personal_bugs, :only => [:new, :create, :destroy]
resources :sessions, :only => [:new, :create, :destroy]
resources :passwords, :only => [:new, :create]
resources :users, :constraints => { :id => /[0-9A-Za-z\-\.]+/ }
resources :computers
resources :userdetails, :constraints => { :id => /[0-9A-Za-z\-\.]+/ }

resources :bz2refs, :only => [:index, :update]
resources :bz2ref_activities

resources :sessions do
 collection do
    get :reset_password
    get :recovery
 end
```

end

resources :bz2ref_resources do
     collection do
        get :remove
        get :restore
     end
    end

```
get "userdetails" => "userdetails#index", :as => "userdetails"
get "edit_userdetails" => "userdetails#edit", :as => "edit_userdetails"
get "log_out" => "sessions#destroy", :as => "log_out"
get "log_in" => "sessions#new", :as => "log_in"
get "change_pwd" => "passwords#new", :as => "change_pwd"
post "search" => "pages#search", :as => "search"
get "search" => "pages#search", :as => "search"
get "help" => "pages#help", :as => "help"
get "admin_urls" => "pages#admin_urls", :as => "admin_urls"
get "report" => "timesheets#report", :as => "report"
post "report" => "timesheets#report", :as => "report"
get "incomplete" => "timesheets#incomplete", :as => "incomplete"
post "incomplete" => "timesheets#incomplete", :as => "incomplete"
get "check" => "timesheets#check", :as => "check"
post "check" => "timesheets#check", :as => "check"
get "export" => "timesheets#export", :as => "export"
get "group" => "users#group", :as => "group"
get "group_show" => "users#group_show", :as => "group_show"
post "group_add" => "users#group_add", :as => "group_add"
get "computer_wake" => "computers#wake", :as => "computer_wake"
get "mirror_users" => "users#mirror", :as => "mirror_users"
get "kiosk" => "posts#latest", :as=> "kiosk"

get "lookupbug" => "timesheets#lookupbug", :as =>"lookupbug"
```

I call upon userdetails controller from users and then after editing I want to go back from userdetails --> users.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you give an `id` parameter in the path.

So for example:

```
user_path(@person[:uid]) => localhost/users/firstname.lastname
user_path(id: @person[:uid]) => localhost/users?id=firstname.lastname
```

To fix the second link you need to change from `edit_userdetails_path(id:@username[:UserID])` to `edit_userdetails_path(@username[:UserID])`, without the `id`.

Comment: I made the change you proposed but now my url looks like this:
[link](http://127.0.0.1:3000/edit_userdetails?format=firstname.lastname)
This is the code from the view:
`<li><%= link_to "Remove this user", user_path(@person[:uid]), :confirm => 'Are you sure you want to delete ' + @person[:uid] + '?',:method => :delete ,:title => "Delete user from LDAP" %></li>`

`<li><%= link_to "Edit this user", edit_userdetails_path(@username[:UserID]) %></li>`

`<li><%= link_to "Add to group", group_path %></li>`

`<li><%= link_to "Change password", change_pwd_path(@person[:uid]) %></li>`

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by creating the hyperlink this way:

```
<li><%= link_to "Edit this user", controller: "userdetails", action: "edit", id: @username[:UserID] %></li>
```

This way it works!